# Como fazer RequestContext thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread, demoiselle, concorrência

Em um projeto estou utilizando o componente "demoiselle-scheduler-quartz". Neste projeto várias threads são disparadas e executadas concorrentemente.
O componente "demoiselle-scheduler-quartz" injeta os contextos do Demoiselle (RequestContext, SessionContext, ViewContext, ConversationContext), ativa-os, invoca a execução da tarefa e desativa-os. Mas esporadicamente ocorre ContextNotActiveException.

Olhando o código fonte do Demoiselle observei a classe `br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.AbstractCustomContext`:

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomContext implements CustomContext {

    private boolean active;
    ...
}
```

e comparei com a classe `org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractManagedContext`:

```
public abstract class AbstractManagedContext extends AbstractContext implements ManagedContext {

    private final ThreadLocal<Boolean> active;
    ...
}
```

Não sei se a implementação foi intencional ou um bug, mas existe alguma forma de tornar a `RequestContext` thread-safe?
Tentei implementar uma `@Alternative RequestContext`, mas sempre é injetada a `br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.TemporaryRequestContextImpl`.
Também tentei definir um método `@Produces RequestContext`, mas também não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou claro para mim qual a questão da concorrência. Por isso não vou entrar nesse mérito.

Pelo que entendi você quer criar uma implementação alternativa de RequestContext que não apresentaria esse problema. Assim, para injetar sua implementação alternativa, além de usar a tag `@Alternative` na classe você tem que colocar no seu beans.xml que você quer usar aquela implementação.

```
<beans ... >
...
    <alternatives>
        <class>meu.pacote.MeuContextoAlternativo</class>
    </alternatives>
...
</beans>
```

Comment: Eu já havia declarado a minha implementação no beans.xml como você sugeriu, mas mesmo assim não funciona. Eu acredito que a forma como foi implementado o demoiselle-core impede a injeção de "alternatives" de contexto. Ver: `br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.CustomContextProducer` e `br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.bootstrap.CustomContextBootstrap`